# How to make CSS height: 100% take effect in a varying height container?

Tags: html, css

My HTML has 2 divs inside an outer div:

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="col-left">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the...
    </div>

    <div class="col-right">Right</div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```css
.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.col-left {
    float: left;
    background: cyan;
    width: 80%
    height: 100%;
}

.col-right {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

The height: 100% takes effect only if I set a px height on the .outer class, however, I have a situation in which the height should not be fixed.

How can I use height 100% without specifying in its parent a fixed height?

---

I'm going to use what Layne wrote in the comments.

Comment: You can't. This behavior is part of the spec. For variable height, you must use JavaScript.

Comment: ya Jeff is right I was stuck on this alot in the past

Comment: Can you use jQuery?  I created a function to do just this a little while back.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you want but give it a try: http://jsfiddle.net/cMEKx/

Comment: @Layne love that css trick, didn't work for what I was doing awhile back.  But is a nice tool.

Answer (score 3):

This CAN be done, but it's tricky. You need to let html and body know their height before you can tell things inside of them to be 100 height etc. --- So, if html doesn't have a height, than how will body know what to be 100% of? and on down the line. It's a slippery slope that I slide down every other day.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;

    /* I use this instead of the micro clear-fix in this case - look that up */
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

.col-left {
    float: left;
    background: cyan;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.col-right {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/fdxGZ/

This is also an issue with "sticky" footers and stuff:
Always a battle http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/ziGbE

I hope that helps!

Comment: See this clear-fix to clear floats. Then you can just add a class to your markup on a few key containers and leave out the empty clear divs.  http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/  (current solution as of july 2013)

Comment: @matthiasgh That's a bold statement.

Answer (score 1):

if you tell the tag's parent tags (including html and body tags) to also be 100% height that should fix your issue.  I added max-height as an option, I did not know if you wanted the container to run the length of the whole screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/brandonbabb/SL3FC/

```css
html, body {
    height:100%
}
.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 500px
}
.col-left {
    float: left;
    background: cyan;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}
.col-right {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var outerheight = $('.outer').height();
    $('.col-right').height(outerheight);    
});
```